# Python pandas: Adding different dataframes with different length to a dataframe using name of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, addition

Suppose I have a main dataframe with three columns

```
      A  B  C
   0  7  7  7
```

And I have three other dataframes, each one has only one column but with different length.

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame([2,3,4,6,7,11],columns = ['A'])
df_B = pd.DataFrame([2,3,4],columns = ['B'])
df_C = pd.DataFrame([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],columns = ['C'])
```

How can I add each one of these dataframes to the main dataframe based on the name of column. So the output will be like this

```
    A   B   C
0   7   7   7
1   2   2   2
2   3   3   3
3   4   4   4
4   6   NaN 5
5   7   NaN 6
6   11  NaN 7
7   NaN NaN 8
8   NaN NaN 9
9   NaN NaN 10
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
In [187]: pd.concat([df, df_A.join(df_B, how='outer').join(df_C, how='outer')])
Out[187]:
      A    B   C
0   7.0  7.0   7
0   2.0  2.0   2
1   3.0  3.0   3
2   4.0  4.0   4
3   6.0  NaN   5
4   7.0  NaN   6
5  11.0  NaN   7
6   NaN  NaN   8
7   NaN  NaN   9
8   NaN  NaN  10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [7],'B': [7],'C': [7]})
df_A = pd.DataFrame([2,3,4,6,7,11],columns = ['A'])
df_B = pd.DataFrame([2,3,4],columns = ['B'])
df_C = pd.DataFrame([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],columns = ['C'])

df_main = pd.concat([df_A, df_B, df_C], axis=1)
newdf = df3.append(df_main).reset_index(drop=True)
newdf
```

You do not have to create the empty dataframe before using the concat.

[pandas documents to read](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault, I didn't explain my question well. I have updated the original question